# SO3(2-) to Na2S2O5 ratio

Tags: solutions, concentration

Is there a way of calculating the amount of sodium metabisulfite from the sulfite content?

I found online instructions for the test kit for sulfite that suggests multiplying by $2.37$ to obtain $\pu{mg/l}$ of $\ce{Na2S2O5}$ from the $\pu{mg/l}$ of $\ce{SO3}$ found in a sample.

Where did they get that $2.37$ from?

This is the formula I came up with:

$$\frac{\pu{mg/l} (\ce{SO3}) \times \text{total volume} \times M(\ce{Na2S2O5})}{M(\ce{SO3})}$$

i.e.

$$\frac{\pu{5 mg/l} (\ce{SO3}) \times \pu{100 L} \times \pu{190.107 g/mol}}{\pu{80.063 g/mol} \times 100} = \frac{5 \times 100 \times 190.107}{80.063 \times 100} = \pu{27.306 g} (\ce{Na2S2O5}) \text{ in 100 liters}.$$

Comment: Where's the online that indicates `2.37?`? What exact ratio do you need? SO3:S2O5?